# PHP date function performance

Tags: php

On quite a large site I am considering adding a line of code that creates a constant for the current date, using date('U').

This is because a vast amount of pages uses this function.

To me it seems lightweight enough to include in the site header, would this be considered bad practice?

Comment: You haven't told us enough.  Define *"quite a large site"*

Comment: Adding a constant will only benefit you if you use a lot of `date()` calls on each page. A constant will not be saved over several request, and especially not for more than the current user.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you will never ever have to worry about the performance of `date()` (and similar functions). However, `time()` is probably a slightly faster substitute for `date('U')`.

Comment: I know this is closed, but I think this may be relevant: I create a $today var at the top of pages that have a lot of queries looking for the current date and then drop the var into my query instead of using "CURDATE()" in MySQL so the query can get cached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"** - this saying should be pinned at every developer's workplace.

If you find such a constant *useful* - you're welcome to define it in the site bootstrap file.
But nor this constant nor direct call to `date()` will never affect overall performance of your site.